# Getting "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" for majority of the users IAP

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-store

My users have been experiencing this in app purchase problem where only half or sometimes quarter of my users have been able to successfully make the auto-renewal in app purchase. After a bit of research on the web I couldn't find any solutions and contact with Apple. As you can imagine, it takes ages for them to get back and even ask the device logs. Some background information; no issues on the development environment and on the TestFlight. This issue only occurs on the production environment. Also I have checked the iOS versions, device models and countries there is no pattern for failed users. While I was waiting Apple to respond I did my best to investigate the issue and tried couple of things to do further debugging.

I released a new update with a newly created subscription group and a subscription through iTunes Connect, rewrite the whole IAP code and put analytics trackers in every step of the purchase to be able to get the error logs.

After the release I waited for couple of hours and I saw plenty of users who couldn't make the purchase. What's interesting is 26 out of 52 users have successfully made the purchase, but the rest has faced this issue. Also the same error log appears for all the users who have faced this problem;

> Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

I googled the error online but couldn't find any solutions or understand the meaning of this error.

Now I implemented SKError to get further logs.

I tried to make the purchase on 4 different devices in the production environment and all of them have successfully made the payment.

Also one of my users emailed me complaining she has received a confirmation email from Apple saying she has been charged but the premium features weren't enabled. Which is more interesting now we know they get charged.

From the analytics trackers I can tell that;

1) The app fetches available products successfully

2) The transactionState becomes "purchasing" when the updatedTransactions delegate method gets called.

3) Then the transactionState becomes "failed" when the updatedTransactions delegate method gets called the second time.

4) I received the aforementioned error in the failed block from trans.error.debugDescription.

5) Since the transactionState is failed, I don't verify the receipt with my backend hence the premium features not enabled.

This is all I know. I would be grateful if anyone can help me with this problem. It looks like it will take ages to Apple resolve the problem and I'm losing paying users.

You can also check my IAP code from the below link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/328si32e73nizyc/IAPHandler.swift?dl=0

Comment: There was another similar question - IAP, developer devices work, a chunk of user devices do not - recently. I wondered if you asked it, so I checked out your prior questions. Is your *current* code still involving Ruby on Rails or something on your server? It seems that might be a place to check things out.

Comment: This thread could be interesting for you, even it is for non-auto renewal IAP's. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88973?sr=stream&ru=17317

Comment: @dfd the Ruby on Rails question was another app and that one works fine. Tried to research online about this issue but couldn't come across any solutions to it.

Comment: @AlexWoe89 this was very helpful thanks!

Comment: Any progess on this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in one of my app, a huge chunk of users cannot complete the purchase and I get the same error (sometimes with [0] or [4] but always "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by implementing event trackers on my IAP handler.

It turned out when the users tap the subscribe button on my app and then tap cancel on Apple's IAP alert view

```
paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
```

the above observer returns a "paymentCancelled" error for the transaction and you can debug this by sending `transaction.error` to your analytics event tracker software (e.g Mixpanel). You can also get detailed log of this error by doing as follows

```
AnalyticsManager.recordEvent(name: "IAP - Transaction Updated", properties: ["Transaction Error": "\(transaction.error.debugDescription)"])
```

After I added these events on my app and released the update, I could quickly see that the "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" error happens mostly when the user decides to leave the payment process, in other words tapping cancel on Apple's IAP alert view. Hope this is helpful.